# After setup virtual host, my wampserver has strange behavior

Tags: wamp

After changing the VirtualHost setting on `httpd-vhosts.conf` in my wampserver like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot “C:/wamp/www/project”
     ServerName project.dev
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

I cannot access my default `index` page of wamp. I got my `project.dev` homepage when I only type `http://localhost'.

Did I do something wrong when setup the virtual host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `httpd-vhosts.conf` file (and other config file that you have put virtual host configs) to make sure that the first virtual host has the `DocumentRoot` is your default `www` folder.

In most case, adding this configuration on **top** of your `httpd-vhosts.conf` may helps:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot “path/to/your/www/folder”
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, can you explain why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

Your WAMP now knows what it should do when a request for project.dev comes in, but your computer still has no idea what is project.dev. To tell it, you need to edit your hosts file (it's located in something like C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc for Windows XP), and add this at the bottom.

```
127.0.0.1      project.dev
```

After this, your domain should be working.

Comment: Thank you, but my domain still works. My proplem is the localhost still point to the new "domain".

Comment: I assume you mean your computer resolves to project.dev, i.e., points to localhost. You never change localhost to anything in your resolver.

Answer (score 0):

You've duplicated the virtualhost tag in the config, instead of opening and closing it. Also make sure that project.dev actually resolves to your host, e.g., ping project.dev